# Missing translated labels in text & media content element

Tags: typo3, typo3-8.x

In my TYPO3 8.7 installations, see the linked image, some german translations of image related labels are missing, e.g. width and height are in english. Does anybody know this problem and how to solve it? I have downloaded the language packages several times and the german translations are really existing, so it must have another reason. I could overwrite the labels manually by tsConfig but I would prefer to solve the real problem.

[image]

[Screenshot of text media element with english labels instead of german translated labels](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EvuXR.png)

Comment: Seems like your image is missing.

Comment: thanks, you are really fast, the link text was missing. I added it know.

Comment: You can support translations on https://translation.typo3.org/
Server will be back soon.

Comment: have you verified that translations are used in the field configuration instead of static texts? (BE module `Confguration` -> `TCA` -> e.g. `tt_content > columns > imagewidth > label` and also in `tt_content > ctrl -> palettes > image_settings -> showitem`

Comment: I have the same problem with TYPO3 8.7.13. I have  verified that translations are used in the field configuration instead of static texts.